# Намертво виснет новый пк

Tags: linux, железо, пк

Купил новый ПК. Установил Kubuntu. Но поработать на нём не получилось, тк завис намертво. При перезагрузке нормально функционирует некоторое время, потом опять виснет. Не могу разобраться в чём проблема(
Ссылка на конфигурацию пк: https://www.dns-shop.ru/custompc/configuration/998f679545fd112e/
[image: материнская плата и процессор]

Comment: И что нам даст ваши комплектующие? Если вы ставите Linux, вы должны понимать, что просто поставил ОС и работаю - может быть не достаточно, нужно уметь работать в консоли и уметь анализировать системные логи.

Comment: Иногда видео драйвера падают, попробуйте с сайта установить https://www.amd.com/ru/support

Comment: Что значит "завис намертво" ? При нажатии на клавишу "Num Lock" лампочка переключается? Можно перейти в консоль по нажатию Ctrl/Alt/F3 ? Лампочка HDD моргает?

Если ничего не остаётся, кроме перезагрузки, запомните время, когда нажали на кнопку сброса и, после перезагрузки, первым делом посмотрите syslog и dmesg. Найдите там (по времени записи сообщений) момент начала последней загрузки. И посмотрите ПРЕДШЕСТВУЮЩИЕ сообщения. Почти наверняка, в нескольких этих строках будет важная информация - куда смотреть дальше.

Comment: Воувоу. `Goodram` - это как Abibas. Вроде бы конечно всё ок, но я бы не стал её даже забесплатно брать.

Comment: @Sergey при зависе по железу какую-то инфу не реально. тут должен быть кернел паник, но производители дров не очень любят писать безопасный код)

Answer (score 1):

Для Rysen на линукс во первых надо обновить прошивку материской платы. Делал я это прямо из БИОСа.

Потом нужно поставить фирмваре на видео. Я использую большую сборку https://github.com/q3aql/drivers-linux-firmware

```
dpkg -i drivers-linux-firmware_20191103-1_all.deb
```